# Can I put an EventListener on an <option> element?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom-events

I am trying to add an `EventListener` to an `<option>` Element.

I tried various ways, yet without result.
I'm working with VueJS, so I tried to use their event-binding mechanic.

**VueJS - Event Binding** - works only on `<select>`

```
<select @mouseover="testValue = true" @mouseleave="testValue = false" ref="select">
  <option v-for="(option, index) in selectionSet" :key="index"
          :value="option.id" :disabled="option.disabled" @mouseover="testValue = true" @mouseleave="testValue = false">
    {{option.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

so naturally I went the RAW plainJS way next.

**PlainJS - AddEventListener()** - The elements are valid, yet the eventListener will not be registered

```
this.$refs.select.options.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('pointerover', () => { window.console.log('AAAAH'); });
  if (!el.disabled) window.console.log(el.value);
});
```

And yes I went with multiple event names.

---

**So what to do?** -> *read the docs*

Looking into the [`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option), I can see, that the `<option>` has the [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement) DOM Interface. This interface is supposed to have all Properties and Methods inherited from [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

> The HTMLOptionElement interface represents  elements and inherits all properties and methods of the HTMLElement interface. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement)

So I'm wondering, can I somehow register eventListeners to an `<option>` Element?

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. Please explain your usecase and we can answer with something that might be what you want and not what you think you want :)

Comment: The use case should be pretty obvious. I want to trigger a function on mouseOver on an <option> element. That's the critical point for me.

Comment: You will need to use select2 or some other widget. You will not find good cross browser mousover triggering on options

Comment: @D.Schaller Seemingly you can only listen to the `change` event fired by the parent `<select>` element itself, if the user changes its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't so much registering the event handler on the element, it's that browsers don't fire events at `option` elements (or at least, not reliably cross-browser) in drop-down `select` elements.

Chrome and Firefox, for instance, don't fire any events on `option` elements in drop-down `select` elements as far as I can tell, even though you can register event handlers on them and even fire your own events on them. In the below, for instance, no events are automatically fired at `option` elements by Chrome or Firefox, but if you click the button to explicitly fire one at it, it works:

```js
const option = document.querySelectorAll("option")[1];

function optionEventHandler(event) {
    console.log(event.type, this.textContent);
}

// None of these fire on Chrome except when code explicitly
// does it with `dispatchEvent`, as far as I can tell:
for (const eventName of ["click", "mouseover", "pointerover", "mouseenter"]) {
    option.addEventListener(eventName, optionEventHandler);
}

document.querySelector("select").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("click on select", this.value);
});

// Explicitly firing an event at the element:
document.querySelector("input[type=button]").addEventListener("click", function() {
    option.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
});
```

```html
<select>
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
<option>E</option>
</select>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Send 'click' to B">
</div>
```

So sadly, if you want to do something when the pointer is over the option, you'll have to use something other than `select` and `option`. Neither Chrome nor Firefox even fires `pointerover` at `document` when the pointer moves from one `option` to the next in a list.

For completeness, note that some events (including `pointerover`) work in non-dropdown `select` elements, at least on Chrome and Firefox:

```js
const option = document.querySelectorAll("option")[1];

function optionEventHandler(event) {
    console.log(event.type, this.textContent);
}

// None of these fire on Chrome except when code explicitly
// does it with `dispatchEvent`, as far as I can tell:
for (const eventName of ["click", "mouseover", "pointerover", "mouseenter"]) {
    option.addEventListener(eventName, optionEventHandler);
}

document.querySelector("select").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("click on select", this.value);
});

// Explicitly firing an event at the element:
document.querySelector("input[type=button]").addEventListener("click", function() {
    option.dispatchEvent(new Event("click"));
});
```

```html
<select size="5">
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
<option>D</option>
<option>E</option>
</select>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Send 'click' to B">
</div>
```

Comment: That's sad to hear. Damn. Thanks for your information. So either I craft my own <select> or I have to drop my planned feature.

Comment: @D.Schaller - I realized I'd only mentioned drop-down selects, but things are slightly different for non-drop-down selects. I've updated the answer. Probably doesn't help you thought. :-)

Comment: Maybe, but not necessarily. I will let that info sink in for a while and re-evaluate whether it might make sense to either use a non-dropdown, or ditch the feature.